# Debian on VM has web access but can't be pinged

Tags: debian, ip, virtual-machines, internet, ifconfig

I have just installed Debian on a Virtual Machine.

I have internet access on the VM and installed SSH. I then did a `ifconfig` and discovered that the IP address is `10.0.2.15` which is strange as the IP should be something like `10.0.0.15`.

I can ping my Windows machine from the VM but can't ping the VM from my Windows machine. I can run other Debian VMs and ping them and they all have the IPs `10.0.0.7` for example.

The firewall isn't the issue, as I can ping my other machines, but I have switched that off for in case as well.

This is a fresh installed on a VM with DHCP enabled, there is nothing strange or funny that I did.

I have tried changing the IPs:

```
# ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.15 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
# route add default gw 10.0.0.2
```

Then I lose internet access and I can't ping my Windows machine. It's strange as it's only this VM doing this.

Comment: How is the VM connected to the rest of the network? NAT? Bridged? Is it running on a installed Hypervisor like VMware Workstation or is it a barebone Hypervisor?

Comment: How is the ICMP configuration on kernel? Maybe the machine is simply ignoring ping requests.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, VM is connected via Bridged. All I am running is Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.

Comment: @Envite I have no idea. This has just been installed, Like I have installed my previous 3 Debian VM which works.

Comment: Have you double checked the network configuration on the host? this sounds very much like a NAT setup.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I dunno what I have then. I have Debain in a VM thats all I know :/. And I am tryna access that VM from the same computer